# How to add a UV bump map to a texture without the node editor?

Tags: normal-map, bump

I want to add a bump map to a texture.

I have color texture: *chairleaftexture.png*, which displays correctly using UVs.

Further down, I found a *bump map* input and "normal". 
I choose *normal map* in the input field and entered *chairleafbump.png* in the color field with the color space set to non-color.

What happens next is my bump map shows, but not my original color of the chair. It's like chairleafbump.png is completely taken over as some type of see through texture?

Comment: hello, please show a screenshot of your node setup or even share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have to downvote this question as, although I understand frustration with new software, the tone is highly charged and does not conform to the [Code of Conduct](https://blender.stackexchange.com/conduct).  Not to discourage you, taking some time to rephrase your question as a considered request for assistance, should bear some fruit for you.

Comment: I removed some paragraphs from which I couldn't deduce any information. If I have removed any important info, please add it back. You should also specify your render engine (internal / eevee / cycles).

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this without the node editor, it's not a good approach since even simple materials create a long list of properties. This is how convoluted it looks like without using nodes:

[image: Property panel]

The exact same solution in the node editor:

[image: Node editor]